# counting number of unique rows within 2 columns

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I have a data file which a part of it looks like this:

```
4 1
5 2
1 2
3 1
1 1
1 2
1 1
1 1
2 1
2 1
```

I want to count similar rows and put my counts in a third column like this:

```
    4 1 1
    5 2 1
    1 2 2
    3 1 1
    1 1 3
    2 1 2
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: You can do this a few ways: `sort` | `awk` once you are sorted you can assume that once you see an input change you can print the total. Using `perl` you can build a hash table where each line is a key and the value is how many times you have seen it and then at the end of input you can print out the map; try to get the key if it fails add it with value 1, if it succeeds add 1 to the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html):

```
$ mlr --nidx uniq -g 1,2 -c file
4 1 1
5 2 1
1 2 2
3 1 1
1 1 3
2 1 2
```

or, equivalently

```
mlr --nidx count-distinct -f 1,2 file
```

Unlike `awk` arrays or `perl` hashes, Miller *appears* to preserve the "seen order" of the keys - but I don't know if that's guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way.  Sort the file, then get counts using `uniq -c`, then use `awk` to flip the field order around.

```
$ sort file.txt | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2,$3,$1 }'
1 1 3
1 2 2
2 1 2
3 1 1
4 1 1
5 2 1
$
```

And a second way, using pure `awk`.

```
$ awk '{ x[$0]++ } END { for(a in x) { print a,x[a] } }' file.txt
1 1 3
1 2 2
4 1 1
2 1 2
5 2 1
3 1 1
$
```

Third way, `perl`.  Bit hacky/lengthy, so waiting on someone to show a more elegant approach.

```
$ perl -nle '$a{$_}++;END{for(keys %a) { print $_," ",$a{$_} } }' <file.txt
3 1 1
1 2 2
5 2 1
1 1 3
2 1 2
4 1 1
$
```